# How to configure ssl certificates and keys for confluent kafka python client?

Tags: ssl, confluent-platform

I am using confluent-kafka. I've to retrieve messages from kafka-broker using ssl. Now, I've configured broker using these properties (partial):

```
listeners=SSL://:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol = SSL
```

Console consumer/producer seem to be working fine with this ssl configuration. 
For console consumer/producer, I am having following configuration:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/home/ubuntu/kafka1.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<intentionally>
ssl.keystore.location=/home/ubuntu/kafka1.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<intentionally>
ssl.key.password=<intentionally>
```

Now, from console perspective things are working fine.

I am having problem in figuring out how to connect to broker using python-client consumer (with ssl enabled).
Documentation talks about these 3 properties to be set:

```
ssl.ca.location
ssl.certificate.location
ssl.key.location
```

But, does not mention where or how to get data for these guys.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To configure these properties, you have to create x509 compliant certificates using OpenSSL instead of keytool. See [this](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SSL-with-librdkafka) page, here is explained how to create the x509 certificates.